# Windows 10 updating from Windows 7 via Windows update fail after 84%

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, dell-xps

I have Dell XPS-L502X(Early 2011) with **Windows 7 Home Premium-64 bit**. I already **reserved my Windows 10** copy and **started an update** to it that was **2,712.6 MB and failed after 84%**, it took for that **17 hrs** as i have 512 kbps net speed. I tried many times to continue that update but it won't progress. I tried **Update troubleshooter** it gives me an error as *"Service Registration is missing and Corrupt" and "Windows Update Error 0x80070057(2015-08-02-T-08_01_52A)" are not fixed.*
P.S.- I have Windows 7 from my Dell Manufacture which is not a crack version. 
Please help me to get that most awaited update.

Comment: run the sfc tool

Comment: Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: share the file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log.

Comment: [Perform a clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135), then run the installer.

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happened to me (Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, desktop computer). I spent the better part of the day trying to upgrade via various methods (Windows Update, Media Creation Tool) with no success.

In the end, I had to clean install Windows 7 and upgrade from that. Went off without a hitch.

So, I would recommend backing up all of your files (should be done regardless), reinstalling your laptop, then trying the upgrade again, Also, since you're on a slow connection, I'd also recommend Microsoft's Media Creation Tool (https://preview.onedrive.com/office365promo/) to download an ISO or USB installation media so you only have to download it once. To upgrade from an ISO or USB, just browse to them and run "Setup."

And after all of that, I would recommend clean installing Windows 10 once you've successfully activated it on your hardware (once your hardware has been registered with Microsoft (this is automatically done when Windows 10 is activated the first time after the upgrade), any Windows 10 clean installs in the future will automatically activate without a key (so just click "skip" whenever prompted for one when installing)), as I've read of problems being caused by remnants of the previous OS.

Comment: Upgrading a clean install of Win7 is of course much better as you say. I would even go a step farther and after upgrading and getting the key (write it down). Doing a clean install of Win10 aswell to be sure there are no leftover Win7 components lying around.

Comment: @ChristianIsaksson I completely agree, and that is what I ended up doing in my situation. I've read too many stories online of people having issues later on because of remnants of the previous OS. Just updated the answer with a recommendation to do just that.

As for "getting the key," I don't believe that is the case for Windows 10 (at least I never got a key). Based on what I know of the process, upon first Windows 10 activation it registers a unique hardware ID with Microsoft, and in future clean installs, Windows 10 calls home and if you're in their database it will automatically activate.